# Api not responding with any venues

Tags: foursquare

If I add a category ID to my api call nothing returns.

If I remove categoryID from url it then works.

?

EDIT -----

I got it to work again.

**removed the following category ids:**
4bf58dd8d48988d1db941735,
4bf58dd8d48988d1dc941735,
4bf58dd8d48988d1dd941735,
4bf58dd8d48988d1d9941735,
4bf58dd8d48988d1da941735

POST Call sample (removed my lat/lng)

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=MY_LATITUDE,MY_LONGITUDE&v=20111107&radius=250&limit=30&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d116941735,4bf58dd8d48988d117941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1d7941735,4bf58dd8d48988d11e941735,4bf58dd8d48988d118941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1d8941735,4bf58dd8d48988d119941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1d5941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1d6941735,4bf58dd8d48988d122941735,4bf58dd8d48988d123941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1cc941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1cf941735,4e0e22f5a56208c4ea9a85a0,4bf58dd8d48988d14b941735,4bf58dd8d48988d110941735,4bf58dd8d48988d111941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1c1941735,4bf58dd8d48988d150941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1d2941735&oauth_token=
```

Comment: Please post the exact calls that you are making, with and without the categoryId

Comment: Is this question still open? If not, please close. If so, can you clarify what the current problem is?

Comment: well, is there a reason why these category ids not valid any more?  Did something change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The category IDs you gave are not listed on https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/categories.

When did this request last work? Category IDs are generally quite stable... I'm not aware of them changing anytime recently.

Comment: They where pulled @ August of 2011, from that link.  It's ok now.